# JMeter Hide first iteration

Tags: jmeter

In JMeter I want to hide the first iteration of my loadtest for caching issues and warmup. For now I have an JSR223 PostProcessor with the next code above each request:

```
if (vars.getIteration() == 1) {
    prev.setIgnore()
}
```

This works good, but the results in the aggregate report are incorrect. The transaction controllers are showing with empty numbers and the calculations of the 90% are incorrect. How can I only fill an aggregate report the second iteration?

Testplan:

- jp@gc - Ultimate Thread Group
  |> Transactioncontroller |> Sampler

An setUp thread is not working because the cache is not shared between threads

The syntheis report is now:

[image]

Comment: Deleting not required trasaction from the csv/report and again load the modified report in the aggregate Listener by browsing the modified file, will give you the desired result.Is it helpful or you are looking for a way to hide automatically.

Comment: True that, this load test is integrated in our CI/CD process and we want avoid manually work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you have only one sampler under the Transaction Controller - you don't need the Transaction Controller at all therefore your approach should start working
2. Instead of ignoring the result you can change the sampler labels for 1st iteration like:

   ```
   if (vars.get('__jm__jp@gc - Ultimate Thread Group__id').equals('1')) {
       prev.setSampleLabel('IGNORE ME')
   }
   ```

   and once done you can strip them off via i.e. [Filter Results Tool](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/FilterResultsTool/), the tool can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager/) and [can be executed via command-line](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/FilterResultsTool/#Usage-and-Parameters) like:

   ```
   FilterResults.bat --output-file final.jtl --input-file your-test-results.jtl ----exclude-label-regex false --exclude-labels "IGNORE ME"
   ```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This solving the issue very simple.

Answer (score 2):

Create a setUp thread group with 1 user, 1 iteration.

- Add a Module controller to it
- Map the Module controller to the other thread group to run all the samples.
- If you are running in GUI mode -> create listener for threadgroup alone to get the JTL
- If you are running in non GUI mode -> Add a JSR223 postprocessor to the threadgroup level and not to any sampler and add the below code

  prev.setIgnore()

Comment: You have create a simple controller and place all your samples and then you have to map it..

Comment: It took me a while to figure it out, but it actually works. YOu have to put all requests/tests into the simple controller.